# Why am I getting a 404 error when trying to make a post to my separate front end codebase?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have 2 separate code bases for my front end and back end projects, react.js frontend and Laravel backend.  I'm trying to point my post in the `web.php` file to my front end url upon successful or unsuccessful file upload.

Am I doing it correctly and what would the URL look like in the action
attribute on the `form` tag on the front end? Below's what I currently have in backend end and front end.

I'm currently getting a `404` error and want to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can approach this.  If more information's needed, then please let me know.

`Route::post('http://localhost:3000/dashboard', 'FileUploadController@fileUpload');`

`<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/web/dashboard">`

Comment: Isn't the route suppose to be in `api.php` since laravel is only a backend ?

Comment: @Makdous ah ok, that makes sense!

Comment: Also there is the [Cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) issue that you need to resolve in order to be able to send request from frontend to backend.